# Generating data to match JSON schema with JSON.NET

Tags: c#, json, schema, json.net, jsonschema

I'm sort of a beginner with Json.NET.  I've gotten pretty good at serializing and deserializing typical objects using JsonConvert, but not much more than that.  So this might be a stupid question.

My program receives a JSON schema from a REST server. I use this schema to generate the UI where the user can fill in data.  Then I need to package up the user data and send it back to the REST server.  This data must match the original schema.  I haven't quite figured out how to serialize my data into a format that would be considered valid by the schema I originally received.

Thanks in advance, and apologies if this is a dumb question.

**Update**:

The schema could change at any time and I'd need to be able to handle that on the fly, so a concrete class implementation is out of the question.

Comment: I didn't understand your question. whats the original schema? you can't simply follow the structure of the JSON you received?

Comment: It looks a lot like this: http://json-schema.org/example1.html.  See the summary at the bottom.

Comment: If you look at that example, I just want to know how to generate the data in "Set of Products".   The schema could change so I can't code up a class that I can serialize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more digging and talking to the guy running the REST server, apparently I was making this way more difficult than it needed to be.

In the end, all I needed was a dictionary of key/value pairs, the key being the property name and the value being some data of the type specified in the schema.  Luckily, Json.NET converts those into JSON perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

If the schema could change and you don't want to modify the class and compile the code every time it does you can use [dynamic/ExpandoObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee461504.aspx).

**Serialization example:**

```
dynamic foo = new ExpandoObject();
foo.Bar = "something";
string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(foo);
```

**Deserialization example:**

```
dynamic foo = JObject.Parse(jsonText);
string bar = foo.Bar; // bar = "something"
```

Comment: This is pretty cool.  If this is the way to handle my problem, then does that mean the JSON standard generally assumes you have concrete classes to work with?

Comment: @NielW [JSON](http://json.org/) is simply a data interchange format, nothing more.  It is totally language agnostic; therefore, it makes no assumptions about any features that your platform of choice might have, classes or otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for your input.  It's good to know about the ExpandoObject, but in the end I didn't need it.  I was over-complicating things.  Thanks again.

Comment: @Aviran: I should also mention that researching the ExpandoObject got me on the right track, because a lot of people commented that an ExpandoObject is basically just a dictionary.